# How can I convert list<string> to char**?

Tags: c++, string, list, pointers, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a std::list to char*[size]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714171/converting-a-stdlist-to-charsize)

How can I convert a list of string, list to char** ?
Is there any way using available STL member methods. If not, how can I achieve it?

I am calling a C-function that takes input as char**, from C++ where it has list of strings to send.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the elements in a list are not consecutive in the memory so there is no direct way to convert an list to an array. So what your method should do is allocate a new array and then copy the strings. If you only want a const char array and the list will not change while you use the const char array then you can do the following:

```
void UseListOfString(const std::list<std::string>& l) {
  const char** array = new const char*[l.size()];
  unsigned index = 0;
  for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
    array[index]= it->c_str();
    index++;
  }

  // use the array


 delete [] array;
}
```

If the list can change or you need something different from const array, you will need to copy the strings:

```
void UseListOfString(const std::list<std::string>& l) {
  unsigned list_size = l.size();
  char** array = new char*[list_size];
  unsigned index = 0;
  for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
    array[index] = new char[it->size() + 1];
    memcpy(array[index], it->c_str(), it->size());
    array[it->size()] = 0;
  }

  // use the array

  for (unsigned index = 0; index < list_size; ++index) {
    delete [] array[index];
  }
  delete [] array;
}
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Your second example has at least two bugs: the first `for` loop's contents allocates the wrong type, and the strings are not null terminated (please avoid using `strncpy()`).  Try `array[index] = new char[it->size()+1]; memcpy(array[index],it->c_str(), it->size()+1);`. Using `strdup()` instead might be even better.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I think I believe I have fixed my errors.